# Converting rows into columns through in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please find attach an image, I need a general SQL query (for more than two records) I mean not hard coded. Thanks

[image: s]

Comment: am using Microsoft sql server Managment studio

Comment: This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: i have tried already but not working, can you plz write down exact query for me?? please

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Ask how to do it, not do it for me...

Comment: You're creating several accounts to post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195481/converting-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2008-without-using-aggregate-functio)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0):

--You use sql Pivot to do it. See code bellow

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ItemCode, ItemName,FrnName,ItmsGrrpCod
FROM Table_Name
) AS abc

PIVOT
(
COUNT(ItemCode) FOR [ItemName] IN ([ACT00054],[ACT00056],[ALF00001],[FGC00001])
) AS PV1